# Laravel Breeze & Vite

Tags: laravel, backend, vite, laravel-breeze

I installed Laravel Breeze but got this error :
htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given

I suspect that I did something wrong with vite.php file but I don't know how to fix this problem.

I have reinstalled Laravel Breeze, also deleted vendor folder and reinstalled but to no avail.